# Git rebase when a branch is created from another branch

Tags: git

I have a precondition of:

```
                        H---I---J topicB
                       /
              E---F---G---K---L  topicA
             /
A---B---C---D  master
```

And wanted to this state

```
                                H---I---J topicB
                                /
              E---F---G---K---L  topicA
             /
A---B---C---D  master
```

Does this solves?

topicA> git pull 
topicA> git co topicB  
topicB> git rebase topicA

I've looked into https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase but not saying this scenario. Looking into few other cases as well, but quite not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Checkout each branch and create a "backup branch" on each. Then you can rebase without worry. Or reset using the reflog if something doesn't go right.

Comment: and push will be still same? `git push origin topicB -f `

Comment: @User same as what? The push command you’ve given seems right as well

Answer (score 2):

The commands you have given are correct. It is important to note that rebasing changes the commit hashes in `topicB`, so the end result will look like this:

```
                               H'---I'---J' topicB
                                /
              E---F---G---K---L  topicA
             /
A---B---C---D  master
```

This doesn't effect any of the changes in `topicB`, just those commit hashes.